# res.sendFile doesnt get rendered on client side

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

```
app.use(cors())

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

connectDB()

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const server = app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`))

const socketio = require('socket.io')
const io = socketio(server)
const questions = require('./api/questions')(io)

app.use('/api/users', users)
app.use('/api/posts', posts)
app.use('/api/questions', questions)

express.static(`${__dirname}/client/public`)


app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    console.log('here')
    res.sendFile('/client/public/index.html', { root: __dirname }, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
            return res.json(err);
        }
        else {
            console.log('file sent')
        }
    })
}
)
```

the static file gets sent to client but page doesnt load, can someone help? spent hours on this.I need to send index.html file everytime a route is not defined, basically if a url is entered and no route is a match then return index.html and load client side route. I suspect that the file is not being sent the front end, but in the network tab I can see that it is receiving a response with index.html, no route is being loaded. Attaching a photo of the network tab, plese help me solve this. Also everytime a request is sent to backend I get 'file sent' in the console. is that normal? since Im hitting a route that exist I thought thats abnormal. If I remove the fall back route in my backend server, nothing changes in the front end and network tab.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <div className="App">
          <Navbar />



          <BrowserRouter>

            <Switch>
              <Route exact path='/' component={MainPage} />
              <Route exact path='/news' component={News} />
              <Route exact path='/login' component={Login}>
                {/* {localStorage.jwtToken ? <Redirect to='/dashboard' /> : <Login />} */}
              </Route>

              <PrivateRoute exact path='/createpost' component={CreatePost} />
              <Route exact path='/register' component={Signup} />
              <Route exact path='/housing' component={Housing} />
              <Route exact path='/housing/:title' component={PageLink} />
              <Route exact path='/forsale/:title' component={PageLink} />
              <Route exact path='/forsale' component={ForSale} />
              <PrivateRoute exact path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
            </Switch>
          </BrowserRouter>



          <Footer />
        </div>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

EDIT: as i suspected req.url returns /index.css i dont know how.

proxy is not working when url is entered manually or copied. when i change the url to http://localhost:5000/localhost:3000/signup It goes to the backend route but returns

```
> Server running on port 5000 [0] /localhost:3000/signup [0] file sent
> [0] /localhost:3000/index.css [0] file sent [0] Database Connected [0]
> URIError: Failed to decode param
> '/localhost:3000/%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json' [0]     at
> decodeURIComponent (<anonymous>)
```

Comment: Add the client side code which renders the page

Comment: Question updated @Build3r

Comment: Looks like you MainPage is responsible for rendering the html so you need to paste code for MainPage component
<Route exact path='/' component={MainPage} />

Comment: If you're getting a blank screen then it's most likely you `react-router` that's not properly set up with your `express` app. Look at the network tab in the dev tools and see if your `React` app is trying to load scripts/css/whatever and if you're getting errors for those requests. If that's the case then follow these instructions on how to set this up properly - https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/

Comment: Ive followed every instruction I ever found, no luck. React router renders the routes that have corresponding back end routes, for example if I have /createpost in the front end, and if that exist in the backend route works fine in the front and back end, but for /register in the front end I have /signup in the back end, and it wont work unless the page is loaded throuh links, also most of the routes crash on refresh. Im updating my code with full server codes, please check, i dont get any errors and when a url is entered I get file sent.  @goto1

Comment: please check my last comment @Build3r

Comment: why are you using `.sendFile` rather than `.render`? Have the server do the templating so that it outputs a finished index.html for the client to load in. If you just need basic templating, `ejs` will do just fine and comes with Express, or you can go one step up and use `nunjucks` or something similar. Also, pretty importantly: _never_ set a route to `*` (or `/`) unless it's the absolute, guaranteed, very last route anywhere in your app. Use real routes.

Comment: What do you get if you curl the page? It may be being sent with the wrong content-type

Comment: it wont work, gives an error @mike-pomax-kamermans

Comment: @josh-wulf my proxy is not working thats what i realized, except it works fine with normal routes. when I enter a url like : http://localhost:5000/localhost:3000/signup it goes to the route but returns an error Server running on port 5000
[0] /localhost:3000/signup
[0] file sent
[0] /localhost:3000/index.css
[0] file sent
[0] Database Connected
[0] URIError: Failed to decode param '/localhost:3000/%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json'